# iOS 8, Swift indexPath.row error "unresolved identifier"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I'm currently doing a course to learn the programming language Swift and I'm getting an annoying error which is driving me crazy.

My code:

```
import UIKit

class RestaurantTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

var restaurantNames = ["Cafe Deadend", "Homei", "Teakha", "Cafe Loisl", "Petite Oyster", "For Kee Restaurant", "Po's Atelier", "Bourke Street Bakery", "Haigh's Chocolate", "Palomino Espresso", "Upstate", "Traif", "Graham Avenue Meats", "Waffle & Wolf", "Five Leaves", "Cafe Lore", "Confessional", "Barrafina", "Donostia", "Royal Oak", "Thai Cafe"]

var restaurantImages = ["cafedeadend.jpg", "homei.jpg", "teakha.jpg", "cafeloisl.jpg", "petiteoyster.jpg", "forkeerestaurant.jpg", "posatelier.jpg", "bourkestreetbakery.jpg", "haighschocolate.jpg", "palominoespresso.jpg", "upstate.jpg", "traif.jpg", "grahamavenuemeats.jpg", "wafflewolf.jpg", "fiveleaves.jpg", "cafelore.jpg", "confessional.jpg", "barrafina.jpg", "donostia.jpg", "royaloak.jpg", "thaicafe.jpg"]

var restaurantLocations = ["Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney",
    "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "London", "London", "London", "London"]

var restaurantTypes = ["Coffee & Tea Shop", "Cafe", "Tea House", "Austrian / Causual Drink", "French", "Bakery", "Bakery", "Chocolate", "Cafe", "American / Seafood", "American", "American", "Breakfast & Brunch", "Coffee & Tea", "Coffee & Tea", "Latin American", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "British", "Thai"]


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.restaurantNames.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell

    // configure the cell...
    cell.nameLabel.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.locationLabel.text = restaurantLocations[indexPath.row]
    cell.typeLabel.text = restaurantTypes[indexPath.row]

    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurantImages[indexPath.row])
    cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // create an option menu as an action sheet
    let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "What do you want to do?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    // add actions to the menu
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

    // add call action
    let callActionHandler = { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Not available", message: "Sorry, try again later", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call " + "123-000-\(indexPath.row)", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: callActionHandler)
    optionMenu.addAction(callAction)



    // display the menu
    self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This line:

```
let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call " + "123-000-\(indexPath.row)", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: callActionHandler)
    optionMenu.addAction(callAction)
```

is giving me an **use of unresolved identifier 'indexPath'** error and I cannot see where the error is coming from. I want to use the row number for the last digit of the phone number.

Thanks in advance!
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with your function definition. You missed to specify the argument name there.

Change:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

to

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Comment: There you have it! Thank you, that did the trick! Will look better through the code in the future, haha! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite newbie in Swift too but I think the variable name for NSIndexPath is "didSelectRowAtIndexPath":

```
let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call " + "123-000-\(didSelectRowAtIndexPath.row)", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: callActionHandler)
    optionMenu.addAction(callAction)
```